# Is graphing exponential functions bugged out on Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

Recently, I tried graphing the function z = xy + e^(-xy) using tikzpicture and \addplot3. But for some reason, the graph is bugging out as its thinking that z = 0 for all values (except a few at the edge):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view = {30}{30},
    xlabel  = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    zlabel = {$z$},
    axis on top,
    axis lines = center,
    zmin = 0
]
\addplot3[surf]{x*y + e^(-x*y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is resulting in a graph that looks like:

[image]

But if you graph it somewhere else like GeoGebra (or any other 3d plotting tool) or try to draw it by hand, the value should be 1 along the x and y axis and then increase as you go outward.
Is there any reason this is happening?
(P.S. if I try to set a zmax value I get a "missing number" error probably because the equation I'm graphing increases rapidly and even at (-5,5) z ~ 7.2e+10)

Comment: The output looks correct to me.  That is exactly what this function looks like.  Did you maybe forget to put a z cutoff?  Check out the `restrict z to domain` key.

Comment: Is it? When I looked at the actual graph it looks like this

Comment: Yes, it does look like this. Here is a picture of the function plotted with the tool `gnuplot`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9QQz.png

Comment: It looks like that on gnullot, but the actual graph looks quite different when you graph it on online tools like geogebra and when you draw the graph manually. Using restrict z to domain seemed to make the graph appear correctly